# Parsing xml text including tags using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

I'm struggling to use the tags in order to get text from an xml file **including** the tags.

For example from:

```
[more stuff]<text><s> Something something something </s></text>[more stuff]
```

I'm trying to get just:

```
'<s> Something something something </s>'
```